# Automating a holiday date for any year in Matlab

Tags: matlab, date

The code below gives a decimal day for one specific year.

```
HolidayArrayDate(2) = datenum(2012,01,16,00,00,00); %MartinLutherKingJrBirthday
```

I am trying to make the holiday more general for an input "dataYear" instead of specifying it as "2012". Martin Luther King Jr Birthday is the third Monday of ever year. When i provide it an input of any year 2010/2011/2012/2013/2014 through "dataYear", it should automatically choose the third Monday in January for me. How would i dot this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the first day of the year, 21 days always suffice to find the third Monday. So: get serial date number for first day of the year (with `datenum`); get day-of-the-week for that and the following 20 days (`datestr(..., 'd')`); find the first three Mondays (`find(...=='M', 3`); and finally pick the third one and convert it into date string (`datestr`):

```
dataYear = 2012; %// input
f = datenum(dataYear,1,1); %// 1st day of year, in serial date number format
r = find(datestr(f+(0:20), 'd')=='M', 3); %// find three Mondays from that day on
result = datestr(f+r(3)-1); %// third Monday, in date string format
```

Comment: why does "r = find(datestr(f+(0:26), 'd')=='M', 3);" only go from 0:26? That's only 27 days i believe.

Comment: @user3698120 It should be `20` (corrected now). `0:20` contains 21 days. 21 is the minimum number of days that guarantees that the third Monday will be found

Comment: +1, nice =) Side note: I got to this answer through the Low Quality Review Queue. I'm not sure if someone flagged it, or if all answers containing only code get sent there automatically, but seeing as there are many robot-reviewers, well... :) Thought I should mention it... a shame if the answer gets deleted! :)

Comment: @RobertP. Thanks for the heads-up! Yes, probably a bit of text would have been in order. The code comments explain well what is being done, though